# How can I add a dictionary in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, dictionary

Whenever I am typing anything in my Firefox, every word is underlined red (Firefox cannot find it in its dictionary).

How can I add the default dictionary to Firefox?

(I am using Firefox 3.5.2 on [Red Hat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux).)

---

<sub>I got it! I was using the Malay dictionary.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click inside a text field; in the "languages" submenu you can set the current dictionary and download new dictionaries.

[image: firefox dictionary selection]

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/browse/type:3, select the language, and then it should ask you, if you want to install the dictionary and if you want it as standard.

Comment: now I think I already have a dictionary installed. When I am right-clicking the underlined word, I am getting some nonsense arrangements of letters. (same even after I just installed a dictionary from the page you've mentioned)

Comment: ok, then please open the add-ons configuration-windows and search for unneeded dictionaries and delete them. If this doesn't help, you can also completely deactivate the dictionary-help by deleting all dictionaries in the add-ons window.

Comment: The link is broken: *"Oops! We can’t find that page"*. [A candidate](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/language-tools/).